# How to dynamically add key and value to the ResourceDictionary in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

```
<Application
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="MultiLanguage.App"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="LanguageDictionary" Source="/LanguageResources;component/EnglishResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**EnglishResources.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<sys:String x:Key="add">ADD</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="key">Key</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="stringValue">String Value</sys:String>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="MultiLanguage.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="{DynamicResource add}" Height="48" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10" Click="btnAdd_Click" />
    <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource key}" Height="40" Width="100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource stringValue}" Height="40" Width="100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtKey" Height="40" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtStringValue" Height="40" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

with above code, i get the following window

[image]

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddKeyValue(txtKey.Text, txtStringValue.Text);
    }


    private void AddKeyValue(object key, object value)
    {
        // load the resource dictionary
        var rd = new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary();
        rd.Source = new System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/LanguageResources;component/EnglishResources.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        // add the new key with value
        rd.Add(key, value);

        // now you can save the changed resource dictionary
        var settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(@"EnglishResources.xaml", settings);
        System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(rd, writer);
    }
```

If i click Add button the value should be inserted in the resource dictionary which(EnglishResources.xaml) is already i have. But it is not insert. Please help me out.

**I need Like**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<sys:String x:Key="add">ADD</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="key">Key</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="stringValue">String Value</sys:String>

<!-- the value should be inserted here. But not Insert-->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**After Added**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<s:String x:Key="add">ADD</sys:String>
<s:String x:Key="key">Key</sys:String>
<s:String x:Key="stringValue">String Value</sys:String>

<!-- the value should be inserted here. But not Insert-->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

After i added the value into resource dictionary i get result like above. the **sys** is changed into to **s** and name space are merged as a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with this simple solution

```
private void AddKeyValue(object key, object value) {
  // load the resource dictionary
  var rd = new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary();
  rd.Source = new System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/YOURAssemblyName;component/EnglishResources.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

  // add the new key with value
  //rd.Add(key, value);
  if (rd.Contains(key)) {
    rd[key] = value;
  } else {
    rd.Add(key, value);
  }

  // now you can save the changed resource dictionary
  var settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
  settings.Indent = true;
  var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(@"EnglishResources.xaml", settings);
  System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(rd, writer);
}
```

Usage

```
AddKeyValue("NewKey1", "StringValue");
AddKeyValue("NewKey2", 1000);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if i use this, This is not add the key and value in my resource dictionary.

Comment: @ASHOKA Have you saved the file?

Comment: @ASHOKA you must replace with the correct path to your resource dict file. i don't know where your file locate. it's only a sample code, not a one to one copy&paste code to your code...

Comment: Thanks lot punker76 It is worked out. I can add the value into resource dictionary now. At the same, i have to replace/modify the value by Key. I found some method(Add,Remove,..) in ResourceDictionary class but not Replace or Modify method. is it possible to replace the value in resource dictionary ?.

Comment: @ASHOKA you can use Contains function to check if the key already exists. look at my changed code example.

Comment: Now It is working well. +1 for your effort. Thank you very much punker76.

Comment: now i facing one issue, please help me out. Please see my quest which is edited.

Comment: @punker76 Do you know if there is a way to set the `rd.Source` to the "current" Resource Dictionary? I'm asking this because I am using multiple in my program.

Comment: @Ericafterdark don't know what dou mean with current?

Comment: @punker76 If I'm changing dictionaries throughout the program, I can't just specify a path to one, I have to set the `Source` to the one that is currently active.